# Are ethernet connections trackable?

Tags: ethernet

If I plug into the wall, is it track-able which room the ethernet connection is coming from? If possible, how?

Comment: Your question seems to be about home networking which is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Answer (score 2):

The network admins *may* know, but the internet at large has no idea about ones physical network.

Switches are layer-2 devices and don't show up in a traceroute. One would need documentation and/or access to the switch(es) to know what's connected where. Even then, it's not always easy to track down where something is hiding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You can just follow the cable.

Comment: Fine. Tell me what room my desktop is plug in. You can't because you have no knowledge of my physical networking - you need physical access to that network. Infrastructure wiring is rarely exposed to eyeballs. I can see the cable from the computer to the wall, but where does that wall port go? It's inside walls and ceiling where it's not possible to follow. If someone didn't document what's what, it can take hours to trace. (been there, done that, burned the t-shirt) If you aren't the network admin, or facilities manager, you won't have access to even try.